# Port cURL CLI shell command with multiple forms and file contents to Python

Tags: python, bash, curl

I have a cURL command which I am successfully invoking in BASH, and I wish to port it into Python. The BASH is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

ACCESS_TOKEN="123456789"
METADATA_FILENAME="metadata.json"
AUDIO_FILENAME="audio.wav"

curl -s -i \
-H "Authorization: Bearer ${ACCESS_TOKEN}" \
-F "metadata=<${METADATA_FILENAME};type=application/json; charset=UTF-8" \
-F "audio=<${AUDIO_FILENAME};type=audio/L16; rate=16000; channels=1" \
https://access-alexa-na.amazon.com/v1/avs/speechrecognizer/recognize \
-o response.txt
```

I am currently trying to use the requests library in Python, but cannot seem to decipher the fields/forms. I currently have this, and can't identify how to deconstruct the cURL command into a format compatible with Python:

```
endpoint = "https://access-alexa-na.amazon.com/v1/avs/speechrecognizer/recognize"

r = requests.post(
    endpoint,
    headers={
        "Authorization": "Bearer " + ACCESS_TOKEN
    },
    forms={
        # ???
    },
    files={
        # ???
    }
)
```

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: You don't need the `form` ( `data` ) parameter, just `headers` and `files` . You can post files like that : `files={'metadata':('filename', open('file', 'rb'), 'application/json'}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the [comment by t.m.adam](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/75141964).

It turns out that the last field in the files parameter takes all of the information, separated by semi-colon. I was therefore able to get it working with this:

```
r = requests.post(
    endpoint,
    headers={
        "Authorization": "Bearer " + auth.ACCESS_TOKEN
    },
    files={
        'metadata': (METADATA_FILENAME, open(METADATA_FILEPATH, 'rb'), 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'),
        'audio': (AUDIO_FILENAME, open(AUDIO_FILEPATH, 'rb'), 'audio/L16; rate=16000; channels=1')
    }
)
```

Answer (score -2):

Try using this:
[cURL to Python Requests](https://curl.trillworks.com/)

Comment: This is what happens: https://pastebin.com/4ZJGTrGV - a lot of the metadata is lost!

Comment: Did you try to just type the rest of it out?